# Can a spin-2 field be expressed as a bound state of spin-1 fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, effective-field-theory

This seems like a rather straight-forward question, but I cannot seem to find any literature on the subject.

It's well-known that a low-energy EFT like chiral perturbation theory, for example, can be re-expressed in terms of a Yang-Mills theory coupled to fermions that form a pion condensate at low energies. I am curious if one can pull a similar trick with only bosons and write a spin-2 field as a bound state of spin-1 fields, presumably with the addition of some additional high-energy Yang-Mills-style interactions.

In particular, is there some way to write the Fierz-Pauli Lagrangian for a massive spin-2 field in terms of interacting spin-1 fields + other dynamics?

Thank you!

Comment: [See section 1.2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.6134)

Comment: In particular the [Weinberg-Witten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem) theorem proves this is impossible,

Comment: That theorem concerns massless spin-2 particles, while OP asked about massive spin-2 particles.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew , but as Seth pointed out, the WW theorem only applies to massless particles. If anyone knows of any references that show how massive spin-2 can be written as a bound state, that would be much appreciated.